# How to get a count of how many users each user has referred

Tags: php, mysql, sql, count

I have a table called User_Accounts, In that table I have a column named Referred_By.

When a new record is added to this table the column id auto increments, In my case this is the userid. So if a user has referred another user. say Gary1992 referred James. James would have gary1992's id in the referred column.

So my question.

I am wondering how I can get a count of how many users each user has referred and put this into a view?

Please let me know if you need more information, I have tried my best to explain and really can't get my head around this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Referred_By, COUNT(*) counter
FROM User_Accounts
GROUP BY Referred_By
```

Comment: Perfect, I didnt even know about the GROUP BY :)